# VS Code Api - How to use jQuery in VS Code Extension Development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make a VS Code extension (Using Javascript) which involves in sending an HTTP post request to a web service. First, I tried:

```
npm install node-fetch
```

node-fetch code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch(url, {
  method: method, //POST
    headers: headers, //Authorization Header
    body: JSON.stringify(body) //Data to be passed
})
.then(res => res.json)
.then(json =>{
    console.log(json);
})
 .catch(error =>{
    console.error(error);
});
```

The above code resulted in a dialog box showing an error:

```
The command 'Complete' resulted in an error (commmand 'codosaurus-copilot.complete' not found)
```

In the Problems section of the terminal, I got the following error:

```
This expression is not callable
Type 'typeof import("<PATH>") has no call signatures'
```

The above error does not occur after removing the import/require statement

That didn't work. After that, I tried installing jQuery:

```
npm install jquery
```

jQuery code:

```js
const $ = require('jquery');

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: (request) =>{
        request.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Bearer <API-KEY>");
    }, 
    method: method, //POST
    data: JSON.stringify(body), //Date to be sent
    success: (data) =>{
        console.log(data);
    }, 
    error: (error) =>{
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

This too gives the same error dialog as `node-fetch`

I even tried `const http = require('http');` and using it's `http.request(url, [options], [callback])`

Nothing worked. Any suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about it didn't work? Did you get an error or what do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: When using $.ajax, I got an error called '$.ajax is not a function' and http/node-fetch did not return any response. The exact same code works on my website though

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you had using node-fetch please?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check